# How to find out name of current instance from command-line?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, aws-cli

Is there an easy way to determine (ie, through boto3 or aws-cli), which instance I'm on, from an SSH session in that instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say `which instance`, do you mean the `instance id` or `instance name` or `instance private ip` or `instance public ip`?

Query the instance metadata server.

```
curl 169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id
```

If you want the instance tags:

```
aws ec2 describe-tags --filters "Name=resource-id,Values=instance_id"
```

or

```
aws ec2 describe-tags --filters "Name=resource-id,Values=`curl
169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`"
```

For instance's private IP:

```
curl 169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4
```

For all available values:

```
curl 169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
```